# Making SketchApp pages interactive and link to other pages

Tags: interactive, sketch-3, sketchapp

I have stumbled across the ability before and cannot find it to save my life. I have done research and cannot find anything relevant to help.

What I have done before is I had a few different pages each with a button on them. I want to make those buttons link to the other pages. Again I have accomplished this before by mistake.

Answer (score -3):

try using Flinto + Craft (LABS by InVision). I found this useful and a lot of fun.